# Using "sed" to delete a "\"-continued line matching a pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following file:

```
fff
ff
test 23 34 \
    45 44
rrr
bbb
```

From this file I want to delete the line matching `test`, but this line is continued via `\`-escaped newline and the next line should be considered to belong to that line.

If I execute the command

```
sed "/test/Id" file
```

it will delete only the line that contains `test` but next line, which also belongs to that line.

How can I delete all lines belonging to a `\`-continued group?

Comment: Is the file in any well-known structured (or other) format?

Comment: the file is a config file. the \ character means cause the line syntax it continue on the next line si i want to delete line but if there ixist at the end \ character to delete and the next line

Comment: Sure, but is it a YAML, TOML, or INI file, for example?

Answer (score 5):

Upon matching `test`, enter a loop that accumulates lines until there is no longer a `\` at the end of the pattern, then deletes the pattern space:

```
$ sed '/test/{:a; /\\$/N; ta; d;}' file
fff
ff
rrr
bbb
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about a way to do it in `sed`, but this `awk` program should work:

```
awk 'f{f--} /test/{f=1} (f && /\\$/){f=2} !f' file.txt
```

- This will set a flag `f` to 1 if the current line matches your pattern.
- If the flag is set, and the line ends in a `\`, it will increase `f` to 2.
- The current line is only printed if `f` evaluates to 0, i.e. `!f` is true.
- If at the beginning of a line the flag is set, it will be decreased by 1. That way, *a priori* only the immediately matching line will be removed. If `f` had been increased to `2` because of a newline-continuation, the current line will however still be marked for exclusion. If this line, too, is continued, `f` will again be set to `2` so that the next line will also still be marked.

*Note* that unfortunately this will only work if the matching pattern is on the *first* line of the continuation group.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/test[^\n]*(\n|\\\n[^\n]*\n)//' input_file
fff
ff
rrr
bbb
```